# How to get first derivation of equation in matlab

Tags: matlab, equation

I have this equation: `f(a,b,x)=t0-a+(a^2*(1+((x-x0)^2/b^2)))^0.5`

if I want get the first derivative: `df(a,b,x)/d(a,b)` for `x0,t0` = constant and `a,b,x` = array.

is this true if I use this script

```
> syms f; syms t0; syms x; syms x0; syms
> a; syms b;
> 
> 
> f=t0-a+(a^2*(1+((x-x0)^2/b^2)))^0.5;
> f_1=diff(f,a)+diff(f,b)
```

I'm asking because I never get the right plot if I use this method...
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df/d(a,b)` is not equal `df/da+df/db`. Rather, it is `(df/da)/db`.

In other words, you need to write

```
f_1=diff(diff(f,a),b);
```